# Pass js variable value to razor

Tags: javascript, html, razor-2, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a javascript variable called temp. Here I need to take it to razor format variable and pass that value to the Upline column in the database.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor (m => m.Upline,new{ @Value ="temp" });

<script> 
var temp =  decodeURIComponent (vars[1]); 
</script>
```

Comment: `View` is rendered first than `js` is rendered